# Getting error when install libraries from cocoapods: library not found for -lPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Hello guy's I know this question asked many times but no one is solved my problem. I am installing some libraries using cocoapods . I am opening xcworkspace and run my project but iam getting this error.

**`**ld: library not found for -lPods-Qboy
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**`**

I want to install these libraries:

```
pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.2'
pod 'QuickBlox'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'TWMessageBarManager', '~> 1.7.2'
```

## Production pod

```
pod 'QMCVDevelopment', :git => 'git@github.com:QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios.git', :commit => '5bb608405c89bbb3b0189a4e188098f27c2af72a'
```

## For development pods

```
pod 'QMCVDevelopment', :path => '../../QMChatViewController-ios/'
```

## Production pod

```
pod 'QMServicesDevelopment', :git => 'git@github.com:QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios.git', :commit => '84e55c43f028589d9f6304b1224bcdc62926b619'
```

I spent 2 days on this error and finally posted question. Please help to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: which library you are trying to install?

Comment: Some Times I am also facing same problem,Try this go to xcode enable bitcode and run and again disable bitcode and run,This will resolve you problem.Also remove all pod and pod.lock file and install fresh pods

Comment: quickblox, quickblox-WebRTC etc. @BhavinRamani

Comment: jp_mob i did that but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -2):

This can be the reason after installing `POD` you need to open `projectname.xcworkspace` workspace instead of project.

Comment: He has already mentioned in his que. that **I am opening xcworkspace and run my project**

Comment: Can  you share the pod name so I can try with?

Comment: Actually when i create a fresh project and install these libraries it runs well. but I want to integrate in a running project. And in this project it creates problem.See my edited question.